# Use of \small in the equation environment

Tags: equations, fontsize

My equations are a little too large for the normal `eqnarray` environment, so I've been using the `\small` delimiters around the `\begin{eqnarray} ... \end{eqnarray}`. Unfortunately, this causes the the equation numbering to follow in size.

Is there a way to reduce the size of an equation without reducing its numbering?

Comment: `eqnarray` is obsolete, better is to use `align`. Can you give an example to see how you use \small delimiters ? You can look at the mathmode.pdf of Herbert Voss

Comment: I've been using { \small \begin{eqnarray} ... \end{eqnarray} }.

Comment: wrapping `\small` around a display isn't really a good idea.  if you (as you should) don't precede it by a blank line, then the baselines of the preceding paragraph will be tighter than they should be, since TeX doesn't apply baselines until the end of a paragraph.  happens all the time, and most people don't notice it.  yuck!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you are using `amsmath` (although since you're using `eqnarray` you may not be), you can force the equation numbers to always be the same size by adding this code to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketag@@@}[1]{\hbox{\m@th\normalsize\normalfont#1}}%
\makeatother
```

but there's another way if you only need one equation number per display.  put your display, unnumbered, inside a minipage and reduce the size of the minipage by using `\scalebox{...}` from the `graphicx` package.  then wrap the scaled minipage in `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` and *that* will apply a nornal-sized equation number.

Answer (score 6):

You can redefine `\@eqnnum`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 

 \begin{eqnarray} 2x+3 \end{eqnarray} 

 \makeatletter 
 \def\@eqnnum{{\normalsize \normalcolor (\theequation)}} 
  \makeatother

{ \small \begin{eqnarray} 2x+3 \end{eqnarray} } 

\end{document}
```

[image]