# Prevent equation labeling to change sizes

Tags: equations, fontsize

Everytime i change equation font size using `\footnotesize` the label *(for example (3.12))* on the right side also changes its size. Is tere a way to change equation font size but not its label font size? Or maybe even vice versa - to change label font size but not equation font size.

This is how i usually write down equations:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\footnotesize
\begin{equation}\label{eee013}
\begin{split}
f(x) = A e^{-\frac{(x-\textcolor{1}{\mu})^2}{2 \textcolor{1}{\sigma^2}}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: the code that will be used for this when `amsmath` is overhauled is in the answer to [Use of \small in the equation environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14372/).  for convenience, here's the code: `\renewcommand{\maketag@@@}[1]{\hbox{\m@th\normalsize\normalfont#1}}`  (don't know whether this question should now be considered a duplicate.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `\maketag@@@` macro, which is responsible for producing equation numbers in `amsmath`, is defined as follows:

```
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont#1}}
```

You can see that it sets `\normalfont` but doesn't alter the font size, so in your case the number is also in footnote size. To change the size of all equation numbers back to the document font size, add the following lines to your preamble, after `\usepackage{amsmath}`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\normalsize#1}}
\makeatother
```

You can also replace `\normalsize` with any other sizing command, of course.

*Note: please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) next time you ask a question. In particular, you didn't mention that you were using the `amsmath` and `color`/`xcolor` packages, and that you defined a new color `1`. This made your code harder to read.*

### edit:

A drawback of this approach is that `amsmath`'s `\eqref` macro also formats references using `\maketag@@@`. So if you don't want these references to be typeset in `\normalsize`, you could for example also redefine `\eqref`. To do this, use the following code fragment instead of the one given above:

```
\makeatletter
  \def\my@tag@font{\normalsize}
  \def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\my@tag@font#1}}
  \let\amsmath@eqref\eqref
  \renewcommand\eqref[1]{{\let\my@tag@font\relax\amsmath@eqref{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

Then, everything you define as `\my@tag@font` will be used for equation numbers, but discarded for `\eqref` references.

Comment: There is one problem. This solution makes all the oher labels within text look smaller too. Can this be prevented? I want only a label lying next to equation to look smaller and not all the labels.

Comment: @71GA see my recent edit

Comment: Your last edit is awesome, but there is one problem: Usually, under a theorem statement, which is in textit format by default, LaTeX brings the labels without the textit format, but with this hack it shows the labels also italic, which seems weird. how would you fix this bug?

Answer (score 9):

Please always post *complete* documents showing all packages used. I had to make some guesses based on commands used in the fragment.

[image]

You can add `\normalsize` to the command used to set the equation number in AMS alignments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,amsmath}
\definecolor{1}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\normalsize#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\footnotesize
\begin{equation}\label{eee013}
\begin{split}
f(x) = A e^{-\frac{(x-\textcolor{1}{\mu})^2}{2 \textcolor{1}{\sigma^2}}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\begin{equation}\label{eee013x}
\begin{split}
f(x) = A e^{-\frac{(x-\textcolor{1}{\mu})^2}{2 \textcolor{1}{\sigma^2}}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Note putting equations in minipages defeats most of the above and below display space logic, it should only be needed in special cases.

Comment: Sorry, @David, didn't see that you'd beat me to the answer by two minutes ;)

Comment: @benwilfut no harm done, your answer is identical even down to the complaint about lack of MWE:-)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using the [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)-package.
You can change the formatting and style of the equation numbers using

```
\makeatletter
    \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\normalsize(#1)\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother
```

Here I added `\normalsize` just before the opening brace. Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

the small equation, with small equation number
\footnotesize
\begin{equation}\label{eee013-a}
    \begin{split}
        f(x) = A e^{\cfrac{(x-\textcolor{red}{\mu})^2}{2 \textcolor{red}{\sigma^2}}}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\normalsize

for comparison: a normal equation
\begin{equation}\label{eee013-b}
    \begin{split}
        f(x) = A e^{\cfrac{(x-\textcolor{red}{\mu})^2}{2 \textcolor{red}{\sigma^2}}}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

%changing the equation number to 'normalsize'
\makeatletter
    \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\normalsize(#1)\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother

the small equation with 'normalsized' equation number
\footnotesize
\begin{equation}\label{eee013-c}
    \begin{split}
        f(x) = A e^{\cfrac{(x-\textcolor{red}{\mu})^2}{2 \textcolor{red}{\sigma^2}}}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sorry, I have't seen the other two answeres when posting mine... Is there no alert that somebody else already posted something when composing my answere, or have I missed something?

Comment: You should have had an alert that there was another answer and an option to redisplay