# Prevent fontsize command resize equation numbers

Tags: fontsize

I'm copy-editing a paper where the author used `\fontsize` to resize equations:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
 
Normal size equation and equation number:
\begin{equation}
x+y=z
\end{equation}

Resized size equation and equation numbers
{\fontsize{8pt}{0}
\begin{align}
\widehat{P}_1 & = 3 {\left(N + 3\right)} {\left(N + 2\right)} {\left(N + 1\right)}^{2} N^{2} {\left(N - 1\right)} {\left(N - 2\right)} {\left(N - 3\right)} Q_{mult} Q_{1} \label{EQ1}\\
\widehat{P}_2 & = 3 {\left(N + 1\right)} N^{2} {\left(N - 1\right)} {\left(N - 2\right)} {\left(N - 3\right)} Q_{mult} Q_{2}
\label{EQ2}\end{align}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the most cases the resizing is acceptable (ugly but acceptable) but I need the equation numbers not be resized.
Can I get the equation numbers to not be resized?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100147/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, I think this question should be marked as a duplicate. I'd prefer not delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer suggested in the comments I solved with:

```latex
\makeatletter
  \def\my@tag@font{\normalsize}
  \def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\my@tag@font#1}}
  \let\amsmath@eqref\eqref
  \renewcommand\eqref[1]{{\let\my@tag@font\relax\amsmath@eqref{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

provided here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100148/33634

I learned a lot also from egreg and Bernard answers.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is typographically sound.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\let\nicolardi@align@preamble\align@preamble
\xpatchcmd{\nicolardi@align@preamble}
  {&\hfil}
  {&\nicolardi@size\hfil}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\nicolardi@align@preamble}
  {&\setboxz@h}
  {&\nicolardi@size\setboxz@h}
  {}{}
\newenvironment{sizedalign}[1]
  {\def\nicolardi@size{#1}\let\align@preamble\nicolardi@align@preamble\align}
  {\endalign}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &= b \\
c &= ddddddddd
\end{align}
\begin{sizedalign}{\footnotesize}
a &= b \\
c &= ddddddddd
\end{sizedalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's your example, with the needed corrections: I removed all `\left` and `\right` commands and the useless braces; moreover, the `mult` subscript requires `\mathrm`.

```
\begin{sizedalign}{\footnotesize}
\widehat{P}_1 & = 3(N+3)(N+2)(N+1)^{2}N^{2}(N-1)(N-2)(N-3)Q_{\mathrm{mult}}Q_{1}
\label{EQ1}\\
\widehat{P}_2 & = 3(N+1)N^{2}(N-1)(N-2)(N-3)Q_{\mathrm{mult}} Q_{2}
\label{EQ2}
\end{sizedalign}
```

[image]

Explanation. The `align` environment uses `\halign` with a suitable preamble that's stored in `\align@preamble` which defines repeatable pairs of columns. The macro is copied and the copy is patched to add at the beginning of every cell the size declaration given as argument to `sizedalign`. This new environment locally redefines `\align@preamble` to the patched copy, then calls `\align` to do the work.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean with "no useless braces and \mathrm for the subscript". In the example you are using \mathrm for the subscript. Anyway I don't need the subscripts to be always in roman.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi I reworded the comment.

Comment: Ah, ok! Thanks! I know that `mult` subscript requires `\mathrm`.  I would have fixed it later. But thank you for pointing it.

Answer (score 2):

I propose a variant solution with the  `medmath` command from `nccmath`, which reduces the size of math formulæ by about 20 % (so the result will not be exactly 8 pt, but not very different):

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{document}

    Resized size equation and equation numbers
    {\fontsize{8pt}{0}
    \begin{align}
    \widehat{P}_1 & = 3 {\left(N + 3\right)} {\left(N + 2\right)} {\left(N + 1\right)}^{2} N^{2} {\left(N - 1\right)} {\left(N - 2\right)} {\left(N - 3\right)} Q_\text{mult} Q_{1} \label{EQ1}\\
    \widehat{P}_2 & = 3 {\left(N + 1\right)} N^{2} {\left(N - 1\right)} {\left(N - 2\right)} {\left(N - 3\right)} Q_\text{mult} Q_{2}
    \label{EQ2}\end{align}}

    With the medmath command:
    \begin{align}
    \medmath{\widehat{P}_1} & = \medmath{3 {\left(N + 3\right)} {\left(N + 2\right)} {\left(N + 1\right)}^{2} N^{2} {\left(N - 1\right)} {\left(N - 2\right)} {\left(N - 3\right)} Q_\text{mult} Q_{1} }\label{EQ1}\\
    \medmath{\widehat{P}_2 }& = \medmath{3 {\left(N + 1\right)} N^{2} {\left(N - 1\right)} {\left(N - 2\right)} {\left(N - 3\right)} Q_\text{mult} Q_{2}}
    \label{EQ2}
    \end{align}

    Normal size:
    \begin{align}
    \widehat{P}_1 & = 3 {\left(N + 3\right)} {\left(N + 2\right)} {\left(N + 1\right)}^{2} N^{2} {\left(N - 1\right)} {\left(N - 2\right)} {\left(N - 3\right)} Q_\text{mult} Q_{1} \label{EQ1}\\
    \widehat{P}_2 & = 3 {\left(N + 1\right)} N^{2} {\left(N - 1\right)} {\left(N - 2\right)} {\left(N - 3\right)} Q_\text{mult} Q_{2}
    \label{EQ2}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the code for your solution?

Comment: Sorry, it seems I had a copy-paste accident. I'l fix that instantly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your  `\medmath` solution but, in my case, it requires to much work.

Comment: I also tried the `medsize` environment, but unfortunately it does not seem to be compatible with align (don't know whether it is due to the `&` or the  `\\\` ).