# Center beamer equations and decrease the font of the equation number indication

Tags: beamer, equations, split, center

I'm having trouble centering the presentation equations. I've used `\centering`, `\gather` among others and it doesn't want to center.

```
\begin{equation}
\centering
\begin{split}
\scriptstyle\phi = \frac{v_1}{\sqrt{2}\cdot f\cdot N_1}\cdot \int^t_0sin\>\omega t\\
    \scriptstyle= \frac{v_1}{\sqrt{2}\cdot f\cdot N_1}\cdot(1-cos\>\omega t)\\
    \scriptstyle= \phi_{max}-\phi_{max}\cdot cos\>\omega t\\
\end{split}  
\end{equation}
```

[image: Model]

The beamer model I'm using is this:

https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/examen-profesional-itam/xkppkzscmxhc

Comment: Please extend your code snipped to complete, self contained document, which reproduce your problem. After while given link can become dead ...

Comment: Please, add `dt` or `\mathrm{d}t` to your integral. Use `& =` to align equal sings.

Comment: Chekk [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100147/140133) to edit size of equation labels.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear, what is your problem nor how you got showed slide. Using usual way to write MWE  (Minimal Working Example) for `beamer` presentation ehere in one frame are image and equation, compilation of MWE gives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck-portrait}
\caption{Imagem adaptada de ...}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\scriptstyle\phi = \frac{v_1}{\sqrt{2}\cdot f\cdot N_1}\cdot \int^t_0sin\>\omega t\\
    \scriptstyle= \frac{v_1}{\sqrt{2}\cdot f\cdot N_1}\cdot(1-cos\>\omega t)\\
    \scriptstyle= \phi_{max}-\phi_{max}\cdot cos\>\omega t\\
\end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that the equation is not centered in the presentation, it is on the left. I wanted it to look like the image you showed.

Comment: @Dragnovith, than use my example! It produce shoed result of compilation. Without seeing a code, by which you produced showed image, people here can't help you.